# how do i add or insert multiple rows in two columns, at the same time?

Tags: oracle, toad

how do i add or insert multiple rows in two columns, at the same time? i am trying this

```
insert into Gwish_bal(Account_code,Flag) values (
('10192885','I'),
('10146883','I')
);
```

and it is not working i keep getting ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis. i want to  insert a thousand numbers and flag them I. the output i need is a table which looks like this

a

```
ccount code    flag
800000008        I
800000009        I
....
800100000        I
```

Comment: Urgent? Are we doing urgent now?

Comment: hahah sorry mr strawberry, i just am in a tight spot i hope you under stand

Comment: Just so you know, sticking 'urgent' in your post sends it to the bottom of the pile.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
INSERT ALL
INTO Gwish_bal (Account_code, Flag) VALUES ('10192885', 'l')
INTO Gwish_bal (Account_code, Flag) VALUES ('10146883','I');
```

But the more common solution I have come across is:

```
INSERT INTO Gwish_bal(Account_code,Flag)
SELECT '10192885', 'l' FROM dual
  UNION ALL
SELECT '10146883','I' FROM dual;
```

Comment: INSERT INTO Gwish_bal(Account_code,Flag)
SELECT '10192885', 'l' FROM dual
  UNION ALL
SELECT '10146883','I' FROM dual;

Comment: INSERT INTO Gwish_bal(Account_code,Flag)
SELECT '10192885', 'l' FROM dual
  UNION ALL
SELECT '10146883','I' FROM dual;       This one works, thank you but for like a thousand rows eg '100000','I' TO '109000', 'I'. how do i do that

Comment: You can try with a PL/SQL table and FORALL. If you are outside the database, use a statement with bind variables. If you just want the data in the database use sqlldr.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
INSERT INTO Gwish_bal (Account_code, Flag)
VALUES
    ('10192885', 'l'),
    ('10146883', 'l');
```

Comment: This isn't valid Oracle syntax.

Comment: what is the right oracle syntax

Answer (score 1):

Use [this](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/insert.php) syntax:

```
INSERT ALL
  INTO Gwish_bal(Account_code,Flag) VALUES ('10192885','I')
  INTO Gwish_bal(Account_code,Flag) VALUES ('10146883','I')
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

for thousand rows:

```
insert INTO Gwish_bal(Account_code,Flag)
select to_char(level), 'I'
from dual
where level >= 10000
connect by level <= 11000
```

Comment: thank you!! i am new to this. so lets say i want add a thousand rows of account code and flag how would i go about it

Comment: insert into Gwish_bal(Account_code, Flag) 
select Account_code, Flag from table_with_thousand_rows

Answer (score 1):

this should be work in oracle

```
INSERT ALL 
    INTO Gwish_bal ("Account_code", "Flag")
         VALUES ('10192885', 'l')
    INTO Gwish_bal ("Account_code", "Flag")
         VALUES ('10192885', 'l')
    INTO Gwish_bal ("Account_code", "Flag")
         VALUES  ('10192885', 'l')
 SELECT * FROM dual  ;
```

Comment: it didnt work, thank you anyways

Comment: you welcome, i forgot the  SELECT * FROM dual at the end ^^

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to wrap the list.

```
insert into Gwish_bal(Account_code,Flag) values ('10192885','I'), ('10146883','I');
```

Comment: This isn't valid Oracle syntax.

Comment: What version are you on ??

Comment: thank you how do i right the proper syntax or unwrap the list